# When does AEM 6 workflow purge run?

Tags: aem

CQ 5.6 had a 'cron' expression to control the timing for the workflow purge [[1]](http://www.6dglobal.com/blog/new-aem-561-workflow-purge-scheduler-2013-10-03), but this is gone from AEM 6.2 [[2]](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/administering/using/wf-administering.html#Regular%20Purging%20of%20Workflow%20Instances).

What's the default, and can it be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow purge task is now triggered via maintenance window section - http://localhost:4502/libs/granite/operations/content/maintenance.html. You can schedule maintenance windows in daily, weekly and monthly intervals and add maintenance tasks to it. The workflow purge task is part of the weekly maintenance window by default.

Comment: Thanks. It's surprising that I couldn't find this info anywhere in the documentation or elsewhere online.